# import FirebaseCrashlytics while using firebase bom

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm using Firebase Crashlytics and Firebase BoM

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx"
```

The default configuration works ok, but I need to get access to FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()

And here comes the problem. Without setting crashlytics-ktx version it doesn't work.
I have to use

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:17.3.0"
```

instead of

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx"
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you solved it?